# Select and print max value in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to select max value and print but is not working

Does anybody can help me ?

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(price) FROM products WHERE user='".$user."'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$price = $result["price"];
echo $price;
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about what result you're getting versus what you were expecting?

Comment: I have values 1 and 2 inside table, I was expecting value 2 (maximum) but I am getting value 0 (zero).

Answer (score 2):

You are using the alias price, so you need to assign it:

```
SELECT MAX(price) as price FROM products WHERE user='".$user."'
```

Or, you could use the query:

```
select price
from products
where user='".$user."'
order by price desc
limit 1;
```